# jspdf supplied data is not JPEG

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm trying to get jspdf lib to show a jpeg image.

I do this:

```
src2 ="domain.com/images/pxPrescription/active_tick.jpg";
tickedImage = new Image();
tickedImage.src = src2;

src="domain.com/images/pxPrescription/no_tick.jpg";
no_tick = new Image();
no_tick.src = src;

doc.setFont('helvetica');
doc.setFontSize(10);

var basestarty = 190;
var basestartx = 15;
var offsetextra = 6;
var extraadd = 0.5;
var extratextoffsetx = basestartx + 10;
var extratextoffsety = basestarty + 10.5;

doc.text(extratextoffsetx, extratextoffsety, "Distance");

if(jQuery('#extraDist').is(":checked")){
    doc.addImage(tickedImage, 'JPEG', basestartx, (basestarty+(offsetextra)+extraadd), 5, 5);
}else{
    doc.addImage(no_tick, 'JPEG', basestartx, (basestarty+(offsetextra)+extraadd), 5, 5);
}
```

I also load the images into a hidden diff at page load to make sure they are available on the page.

I get Error: Supplied data is not a JPEG

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/issues/708 might help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure since there isn't an environment to tinker with, but you should call

```
await no_tick.decode()
```

or

```
await tickedImage.decode()
```

as applicable in either of your if/else statements prior to adding the image to your pdf to ensure that you have valid image data available and then make your handler code an async function.
You're also welcome to use .then() as shown here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode